# Is there a way to use the current value of Accumulate Field as part of the input?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm almost positive that the answer is a pretty straightforward "no," but I was wondering if there was a way to use the total evaluated at the previous index as part of the input for the Accumulate Field node. Basically, I want to access the trailing value in the calculation. My actual goal was to try and position a series of points relative to each other/their previous positions without needing to have a series of chained Set Position nodes.

Comment: Could you give an example for a formula, that you try to implement? Because, the trailing of the Accumulate Field node is always the last trailing + the Value-Input.

Comment: It's definitely possible I'm misunderstanding what the trailing value is, so maybe disregard that. Unless I'm completely wrong about how the node works, the value input is added to a running total that is being evaluated for each index, and I want to be able to use that total as part of the input formula (say I wanted the input at each index to be half of whatever the current total was).

Comment: I think, it is not possible to use the previous value as an input for your current calculation. In my understanding, this would lead to a cycle in your node net. At least I did not finde a way, to prevent this cycle.
Instead, taking your example, it would be best, to solve it differently. Let's say, y0 = 100 and you want to be y1=y0/2 and y(n)=y(n-1)/2. Then you could set y with the "Set Position" node by using the index with this formula: y = 100 * (0,5)^index.

Answer (score 1):

The "Field at Index" node is your friend here. You can shift any field by adding or subtracting from the index. Then you can accumulate the shifted field and use the result in another node.
[image]